# How do you have the user set the variable?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, user-input

I am trying to have the user set the name for how many numbers they set. for example if they set 3 the program asks for name 3 times and then sets those names to a different varible inside an array.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Num = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner Name = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter: ");
    int number = Num.nextInt();
    int[] numbs = new int[number];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
        
        System.out.println("What is your name");
        
        String [] nameArray = Name.nextLine();
```

Comment: Declare the array before the loop and use `[i]` to access the ith element.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small improvement over Titan's answer.

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter: ");
    int numberOfTimes = sc.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[numberOfTimes];
    sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
      System.out.println("What is your name");
      names[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Starting point

Here are several things happening in your posted code:

- You have two different Scanners, each reading from System.in
- After prompting for user input (`int number = Num.nextInt()`), you're using that number to create an array of size "number"
- When you call [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), you are assigning the result to a string array (`String []`).

#### Working solution

Here's a variation which addresses those issues, with a few additions, too:

- Use one [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and give it a general name ("scanner", not "Num") since a scanner has nothing to do with one specific data type. Any scanner can read strings, integers, booleans, bytes, etc. Look in Javadoc for the full set of supported data types.
- Check if user input is valid before trying to create an array – if user enters "-1" that's a valid integer value, but not valid for allocating an array – `new int[-1]`) would throw a java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException at runtime.
- Use "next()" instead of "nextLine()" – with the rest of your example, using "nextLine()" results in skipping one line without direct interaction from the user (so the first "name" is always an empty string)
- Assign the result of "next()" to a String (not `String[]`), matching the return type from the method
- Use "System.out.print()" instead of "println()", a little tidier program output
- Use lowercase names to follow Java naming conventions ("scanner", not "Scanner")

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("How many names do you want to enter: ");
int times = scanner.nextInt();

if (times < 0) {
    System.out.println("negative numbers not allowed");
} else {
    String[] names = new String[times];
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.print("What is your name: ");
        names[i] = scanner.next();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
}
```

And here's a sample run:

```
How many names do you want to enter: 3
What is your name: one
What is your name: two
What is your name: three
[one, two, three]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a String array of number length outside the loop and initialize each index with name as input.
By the way you only need to create one Scanner object for input(Not needed to create various objects for different input).
**Edit**  - There was no use of numbs array.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter: ");
int number = sc.nextInt();
String []nameArray=new String[number];
/*Since nextInt() does not read the newline character in your input  
created by hitting "Enter"*/.
sc.nextLine();  
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {   
    System.out.println("What is your name");  
    nameArray[i]=sc.nextLine();
}
sc.close();  //To prevent memory leak
```

Comment: Curious...Why use the `numbs[]` array? Why not just `for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {` OR `for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {`? Then when iterating through the Array: `for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) { System.out.println(Supplied Name #" + (i + 1) +": " + nameArray[i]); }`

Comment: This does not work correctly – there is an extra newline in the input which results in an always-blank first entry in `nameArray`. With input "3", "first", "second", the program terminates, and if you add this at the end – `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nameArray))` – the program shows that the array does contain three elements, and the first one is blank: `[, first, second]`

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention both of those issues.